# MongoDB return the latest object based on field and time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am very new to mongoDB and I want to return the most recent entry based on the field `tagDetail`.  My objects in MongoDB looks like this

```
{
  "tagDetail": "99CalcTrigger",
  "value": "2",
  "quality": "Good",
  "timestamp": "2018-12-14T10:45:05Z"
}
```

So there are numerous objects with the same `tagDetail` field (99CalcTrigger) where the value and timestamp change.  I want to be able to return the most recent entry.

So far I have the following:

```
db.TagValues.find(tagDetails: "UMIS.99CalcTrigger.F_CV").sort({timestamp:1})
```

This gives the following error:

> 2018-12-15T19:06:14.756+0000 E QUERY    [js]
>   Syntadb.TagValues.find(tagDetails:
>   "UMIS.99CalcTrigger.F_CV").sort({timestamp:1})
>
> 2018-12-15T19:16:28.441+0000 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing )
>   after argument list @(shell):1:28sort({timestamp:1})

Comment: It's just a syntax error, try: `db.TagValues.find({tagDetails: "UMIS.99CalcTrigger.F_CV"}).sort({timestamp:1})`

Comment: @mickl that doesn't seem to work, nothing happens

Comment: It seems you have a typo, your field name is `tagDetail` not `tagDetails`, try: `db.TagValues.find({tagDetail: "99CalcTrigger"}).sort({timestamp:1})`